# java.io.FileNotFoundException when uploading video file to server in android using Retrofit

Tags: android, video, server, retrofit2

I am trying to compress video before uploading to server using Retrofit. I have tried all possible solutions posted on stackoverflow but still getting same exception. However, as API is hit it is throwing exception as mentioned below:

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.flexyn.debug/files/mydir (Is a directory)**

Below is the method which I am using to save file to internal storage:

```
private File convertVideoPathToFile() {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        file = new File(getFilesDir(),"flexyn_video");
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }else if(!file.isDirectory() && file.canWrite()){
            file.delete();
            file.mkdirs();
        }

        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(file.getName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            outputStream.write(videoPath.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file;
    }
```

Below is the method to call API for uploading video to server:

@Override

```
 public void saveVideoPost(File file) {
        if (mView == null) {
            return;
        }
        mView.showLoadingLayout();
        ApiInterface apiInterface= ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/*"), file);
        RequestBody caption = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), mView.getCaption());
        RequestBody privacy = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), mView.getPrivacyStatus());
        MultipartBody.Part imageFileBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);
        apiInterface.postActivity(tags_ids.toString(),FlexynApplication.getInstance().getUserToken(),imageFileBody, caption, privacy)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<DefaultResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(DefaultResponse responseBody)
                    {
                        if(responseBody.getError_code()==200 && responseBody.isSuccess()){
                            mView.hideLoadingLayout();
                            Log.d(TAG, "uploaded successfully " +responseBody.getMessage());
                            success(responseBody);
                        }else{
                            mView.hideLoadingLayout();
                            error(responseBody.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable throwable) {
    // throwing error here 
                        mView.hideLoadingLayout();
                        error(AppConstant.ERROR_MESSAGE1);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: `file.mkdirs();` will create the directory structure including the directory with the name of the file name. This way after using `file.mkdirs();` you will get a directory.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Sorry, I couldn't get. Can you please help what could be corrected here?

Comment: `file = new File(getFilesDir(),"flexyn_video");
if (!file.exists()) {
      file.mkdirs();
}else if(!file.isDirectory() && file.canWrite()){
      file.delete();
      file.mkdirs();
}`
I think the file object is pointed to a directory instead of a file.

Comment: I am not getting solution to this. What can be done here to fix this?

Comment: To fix this you need you `file` variable to point to a video file and not a directory as you are doing now

Comment: Tried but still not working